# How do I change the style of FindTextBox of FlowDocumentReader to match the theme of my app?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a WPF app with a [`FlowDocumentReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.onfindcommand) control and when I click the search button to search the text, the text box doesn't match the theme of the app.  The text does, but the background of the text box doesn't.  So if I am using a dark theme, the text I type into the text box is white (which is correct), but the text box background is also white (incorrect, making text not legible).

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I tried applying a style but I don't know which component to target.

[image: Wrong text box color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, Microsoft *really* does not make this easy.

---

## My Process

I tried the easy trick of adding a `Style TargeType="TextBox"` to `FlowDocumentReader.Resources`, but that doesn't work.

I tried doing things the "right" way and overriding `FlowDocumentReader`'s `ControlTemplate`, but the `TextBox` in question isn't even part of the `ControlTemaplte`! Instead, there's a `Border` named `PART_FindToolBarHost`. The `TextBox` we want is added as a child to `PART_FindToolBarHost` in code- but only *after* the user has clicked the "find" button (the one with the magnifying glass icon). You can see this for yourself by looking at the control's [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Documents/DocumentViewerHelper.cs,536a6b0641502380).

With no more XAML-only ideas, I had to resort to using code. We need to somehow get a reference to the `TextBox` being created, and I can't think of any better way than to manually search the visual tree for it. This is complicated by the fact that the `TextBox` only exists once the find command has been executed.

Specifically, the find button in `FlowDocumentReader` binds to [`ApplicationCommands.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.find). I tried adding a `CommandBinding` for that command to `FlowDocumentReader` so I could use it as a trigger to retrieve the `TextBox`. Unfortunately, adding such a `CommandBinding` somehow breaks the built-in functionality and prevents the `TextBox` from being generated at all. This breaks even if you set `e.Handled = False`.

Luckily, though, `FlowDocumentReader` exposes an [`OnFindCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.onfindcommand)- except, of course, it's a `Protected` method. So I finally gave in and decided to inherit `FlowDocumentReader`. `OnFindCommand` works as a reliable trigger, but it turns out the `TextBox` isn't created until *after* the sub finishes. I was forced to use [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke?#System_Windows_Threading_Dispatcher_BeginInvoke_System_Delegate_System_Windows_Threading_DispatcherPriority_System_Object___) in order to schedule a method to run after the `TextBox` was actually added.

**Using `OnFindCommand` as a trigger, I was finally able to reliably get a reference to the "find" `TextBox`**, which is actually named `FindTextBox`.

Now that I can get a reference, we can apply our own `Style`. Except: `FindTextBox` already has a `Style`, so unless we want to override it, we're going to have to merge the two `Style`s. There's no publicly-accessible method for this (even though WPF does this internally in places), but luckily I already had some code for this.

---

## The Working Code

First, a `Module` with the helper methods I used:

`FindVisualChild` is used to loop through the visual tree and get a reference to `FindTextBox`.
`MergeStyles` is used to combine the existing `Style` with the `Style` we supply, once we have that reference.

```
Module OtherMethods
    <Extension()>
    Public Function FindVisualChild(obj As DependencyObject, Name As String) As FrameworkElement
        For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) - 1
            Dim ChildObj As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i)

            If TypeOf ChildObj Is FrameworkElement AndAlso DirectCast(ChildObj, FrameworkElement).Name = Name Then Return ChildObj

            ChildObj = FindVisualChild(ChildObj, Name)
            If ChildObj IsNot Nothing Then Return ChildObj
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function MergeStyles(ByVal style1 As Style, ByVal style2 As Style) As Style
        Dim R As New Style

        If style1 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("style1")
        If style2 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("style2")
        If style2.BasedOn IsNot Nothing Then style1 = MergeStyles(style1, style2.BasedOn)

        For Each currentSetter As SetterBase In style1.Setters
            R.Setters.Add(currentSetter)
        Next

        For Each currentTrigger As TriggerBase In style1.Triggers
            R.Triggers.Add(currentTrigger)
        Next

        For Each key As Object In style1.Resources.Keys
            R.Resources(key) = style1.Resources(key)
        Next

        For Each currentSetter As SetterBase In style2.Setters
            R.Setters.Add(currentSetter)
        Next

        For Each currentTrigger As TriggerBase In style2.Triggers
            R.Triggers.Add(currentTrigger)
        Next

        For Each key As Object In style2.Resources.Keys
            R.Resources(key) = style2.Resources(key)
        Next

        Return R
    End Function
End Module
```

Then, there's `StyleableFlowDocumentReader`, which is what I named my extended control that inherits `FlowDocumentReader`:

```
Public Class StyleableFlowDocumentReader
    Inherits FlowDocumentReader

    Protected Overrides Sub OnFindCommand()
        MyBase.OnFindCommand()
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() GetFindTextBox(), DispatcherPriority.Render)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetFindTextBox()
        findTextBox = Me.FindVisualChild("FindTextBox")
        ApplyFindTextBoxStyle()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ApplyFindTextBoxStyle()
        If findTextBox IsNot Nothing Then
            If findTextBox.Style IsNot Nothing AndAlso FindTextBoxStyle IsNot Nothing Then
                findTextBox.Style = MergeStyles(findTextBox.Style, FindTextBoxStyle)
            Else
                findTextBox.Style = If(FindTextBoxStyle, findTextBox.Style)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private findTextBox As TextBox

    Public Property FindTextBoxStyle As Style
        Get
            Return GetValue(FindTextBoxStyleProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Style)
            SetValue(FindTextBoxStyleProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly FindTextBoxStyleProperty As DependencyProperty =
                           DependencyProperty.Register("FindTextBoxStyle",
                           GetType(Style), GetType(StyleableFlowDocumentReader),
                           New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, Sub(d, e) DirectCast(d, StyleableFlowDocumentReader).ApplyFindTextBoxStyle()))
End Class
```

And then, finally, a usage example:

```
<local:StyleableFlowDocumentReader x:Name="Reader">
    <local:StyleableFlowDocumentReader.FindTextBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
    </local:StyleableFlowDocumentReader.FindTextBoxStyle>
        
    <FlowDocument/>
</local:StyleableFlowDocumentReader>
```

Comment: I'm actually stuck converting this to C#, FindVisualChild takes two parameters but you only passed one here `Me.FindVisualChild("FindTextBox")`

Comment: @erotavlas Oh, that's because `FindVisualChild` is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). These are declared by applying the `Extension` attribute to a method. The way I call it is funtionally equivalent to `FindVisualChild(Me, "FindTextBox")`.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working for me.  I converted the code to C# and placed it in a Gist https://gist.github.com/erotavlas/c8a614201ec1cf75c088404152cc61e7 , maybe you can take a look.  My XAML is the same as yours.

Comment: I see the problem is in FincVisualChild method, the children count of the SytelableFlowDocumentReader is 1 so it doesn't go in the for loop and returns null - findtextbox is null, it never is found.

Comment: Actually its working now, I had to remove the ` - 1` in the loop because I was using `<`